# How to prevent WordPress from redirecting when page is not found

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to set up a proper 404 page but am having a difficult time figuring out how to remove the intermediate 302 redirect to our 404 page.

I have looked at our .htaccess file, our apache2 config, and WordPress settings, and I cannot figure out what to do. It was previously doing two redirects (a 302 to 301 to 404), until I added this to our functions.php file:

> remove_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');

But we are still seeing a 302 to 404.

The 302 location is {example.com}/index.php?page_id=5436

My inclination is that this is the result of WordPress redirecting to a custom 404 page, but surely there is a proper way to handle this to avoid the intermediate 302?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDIT] In reply to the following comment:

> Is there a way to serve the 404 page without the redirect?

Try this:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
    if ( is_404() ) {
        include get_query_template( '404' );
        exit;
    }
}, 9 );
```

*Or* this: (you should try with this first)

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
    if ( is_404() ) {
        remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );
    }
}, 9 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but doesn't wp_redirect just replicate the underlying problem? It is creating a 302 redirect. Is there a way to serve the 404 page without the redirect?